# JOLT concatenate ONLY if not NULL

Tags: json, null, concatenation, jolt

I need to change a date from YEAR to a fixed `YYYY-MM-DD` only if the value of the year is not null.

At the moment I have this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Passing?": "=concat(@(1,Passing),-01-01'"
    }
  }
]
```

**Input:**

```json
{
  "Passing": "2022",
  "Comments": "NotMentioned",
  "Team": "2",
  "modified_date": "2023-01-27 13:41:39",
  "Profile": "DM",
  "JobRole": "Tester"
}
```

And the Output I'll like is

```json
{
  "Passing": "2022-01-01",
  "Comments": "NotMentioned",
  "Team": "2",
  "modified_date": "2023-01-27 13:41:39",
  "Profile": "DM",
  "JobRole": "Tester"
}
```

This is currently working fine but when I have a null value in Passing i get this, that I want to avoid.

```json
{
  "Passing": "null-01-01",
  "Comments": "NotMentioned",
  "Team": "2",
  "modified_date": "2023-01-27 13:41:39",
  "Profile": "DM",
  "JobRole": "Tester"
}
```

I need to keep the "Passing" equal to "null" if there is no year in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suffixing **?** operator of `Passing` attribute checks out for the ***existence***, not for ***nullability***.

You rather can use **`isNull`** function within a **modify** transformation spec in order to check the condition such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Passing": ["=isNull", "=concat(@(1,&),'-01-01')"]// the value is overwritten provided the Passing has a non-null value
    }
  }
]
```

where **`@(1,&)`** replicates the current value of the attribute `Passing`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your `Passing` value is if it's not `null`, But you can use the below spec if you want to achieve to your desired output.

Spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Passing": "=concat(@(1,Passing),'-01-01')"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "Passing": {
        "-*": {
          "@": "&2"
        },
        "*": {
          "@1": "&2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

If `Passing` is null, you get **`null`**.

If `Passing` is `2023`, you get **`2023-01-01`**